# Add new custom object to existing profile by metadata api

Tags: salesforcedx, permissions, unmanaged-package, package.xml

I have a few new custom objects in my unmanaged package and i want to give permissions to existing profiles in the target org. How can i do that? What i tried is the following xml file in my package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <objectPermissions>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <object>Object1__c</object>
    </objectPermissions>
    <objectPermissions>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <object>Object2__c</object>
    </objectPermissions>
    <objectPermissions>
        <allowEdit>true</allowEdit>
        <object>Object3__c</object>
    </objectPermissions>
</Profile>
```

There is a profile in the target system called `System Administrator` so i named the file `SystemAdministrator.profile.xml-meta.xml`.
Im getting this error when installing the package:

```
Encountered errors installing the package!,Installation errors: 
1) Error parsing file: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}objectPermissions invalid at this location in type EmailServicesFunction, Details: SystemAdministrator.profile: Error parsing file: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}objectPermissions invalid at this location in type EmailServicesFunction
```

Now im not sure if i did everything correct and its a different problem, or the file above is not working.

Comment: if it is a standard profile -- then it should be called Admin.profile

Comment: @kurunve What if its a custom profile? And how should the file exactly be called? Like just Admin.profile or Admin.profile.xml-meta.xml

Comment: sorry, I did not see a sfdx tag. in sfdx project, it should a profile full name name (```[select id, name, fullName from Profile where name = 'System Administrator']```) and it should be .profile-meta.xml